# How to set the Angular material tab's mat-ink-bar to take the width of tab header text width

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want the Angular material tab's mat-ink-bar to take the width of the tab header text's width. Currently, it is larger than the tab header text width.

The following image shows how it looks now.

[image: Current look]

The following image shows how I want it to be.

[image: How I want the mat-tab-ink-bar to look]

Could you help me how to make this happen?

Comment: The width of the ink bar is following Material Design guidelines and shouldn't be changed. IMO it would be extremely difficult if not impossible to do anyway, due to the way it is implemented.

Comment: If they're not going to allow us to modify their styles to make them usable in our applications, maybe we should stop using their library.  Ridiculous.

Answer (score 12):

[image]
I achieved this by removing min-width and padding on the .mat-tab-label class..
and adding margin as per my requirement to keep the labels apart.
this worked as mat-ink-bar takes the width of mat-tab-label which was set min-width to 160px;

**SCSS:**

```
mat-tab-header {
border-bottom: none !important;
.mat-tab-label-container {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    .mat-tab-labels {
    .mat-tab-label {
        padding: 0 0 !important;
        min-width: 10px;
        margin-left: 95px;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: mat-tab-header {
      border-bottom: none !important;
      .mat-tab-label-container {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        .mat-tab-labels {
          .mat-tab-label {
              padding: 0 0 !important;
              min-width: 10px;
              margin-left: 95px;
            }}}} @shaheershukur

Comment: it's scss code?  i converted it to css. but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I have done it using after and before css pseudo classes, but for cutting a definite amount of the mat-ink-bar width. Please see the below SCSS code

```
  mat-ink-bar {           
                &:before,
                &:after {
                    content: "";
                    height: 2px;
                    width: 20px;
                    background-color: white;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                }
                &:after {
                    left: initial;
                    right: 0;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Suits well if you need to keep clickable areas next to each other so can't use margins.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the background color of existing `mat-link-bar` (using `background-color: transparent`) and create a new style using `pseudo` class.

```
     .mat-ink-bar {
        background-color: transparent;
        &::before {
          content: '';
          display: block;
          width: 90%;
          background-color: #47a1f6;
          height: 6px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 70px;
          left: 5%;
          position: relative;
        }
      }
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of Angular Material (currently 15) you now have the option to use the `fitInkBarToContent` attribute.

```
<mat-tab-group fitInkBarToContent>
  <mat-tab label="Tab">Content</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

See the examples under https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples#tab-group-ink-bar